# Como mudar o formato de um objeto em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um objeto no seguinte formato:

```
[
  {
    "path": "caminho1",
    "subpath": [ { "path": "1" }, { "path": "2" }, { "path": "3" }, { "path": "4" } ]
  },{
    "path": "caminho2",
    "subpath": []
  },{
    "path": "caminho3",
    "subpath": [ { "path": "1" }, { "path": "2" } ]
  },{
    "path": "caminho4",
    "subpath": [ { "path": "1" }, { "path": "2" }, { "path": "3" } ]
  }
]
```

e quero transformar para o seguinte formato:

```
[
  { params: { path: ["caminho1", "1"] } },
  { params: { path: ["caminho1", "2"] } },
  { params: { path: ["caminho1", "3"] } },
  { params: { path: ["caminho1", "4"] } },
  { params: { path: ["caminho3", "1"] } },
  { params: { path: ["caminho3", "2"] } },
  { params: { path: ["caminho4", "1"] } },
  { params: { path: ["caminho4", "2"] } },
  { params: { path: ["caminho4", "3"] } }
]
```

Como faço essa alteração com JavaScript? Eu sei que a função `.reduce()` pode fazer isso, mas eu não consigo entender ela direito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu objeto tem dois arrays, o próprio objeto e a seguir "subpath", por isso precisa interar sobre os dois.

Se não conseguiu entender bem o `reduce`, talvez um `forEach` seja mais simples de entender:

```js
var lista = [
  {
    "path": "caminho1",
    "subpath": [ { "path": "1" }, { "path": "2" }, { "path": "3" }, { "path": "4" } ]
  },{
    "path": "caminho2",
    "subpath": []
  },{
    "path": "caminho3",
    "subpath": [ { "path": "1" }, { "path": "2" } ]
  },{
    "path": "caminho4",
    "subpath": [ { "path": "1" }, { "path": "2" }, { "path": "3" } ]
  }
];

var novaLista = [];

lista.forEach(function (item) {
   item.subpath.forEach(function (subItem) {
    var pathItens = [];
    pathItens.push(item.path);
    pathItens.push(subItem.path);
    
    novaLista.push({ paramans: { path: pathItens }});
   });
});

console.log(novaLista);
```

Basicamente foi criado um novo objeto (novaLista) para adicionar os itens do novo objeto que tem um formato diferente.

Tem duas iterações de `forEach`. Na segunda dos elementos em "subpath" é criado o objeto e adicionado (`push`) a novaLista, acredito que seja simples de entender.

Sobre a função `reduce`, pode ler mais aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Valeu, meu filho, entendi. Eu devia me corrigir em relação ao reduce pq nesse caso aí de um path dentro de um subpath eu não consigo fazer ele aparecer igual, ou só aparece como se fosse uma string tipo "caminho1,1,caminho1,2..." ou só como um vetor [Object Object]